# Ubuntu 17.10 freezes on shutdown or restart - a stop job is running for TLP system startup/shutdown

Tags: shutdown, 17.10

Getting error message

```
a stop job is running for TLP system startup/shutdown
```

Just upgraded from 16.04 to 17.10.

Comment: Possibly related / duplicate: [kworker blocked for more than 120 seconds Ubuntu 17.10](//askubuntu.com/q/965856)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724317

It should be fixed and be released till 05.11.